# How to stop PhpStorm from indexing my `excluded` directory?

Tags: php, indexing, phpstorm

Within PhpStorm 2018.1.6 I've got a directory `x` which I have excluded using `Settings | Directories -> Exclude directory x`. PhpStorm takes care of most of the directories which I have excluded but not this one. While I am editing/creating PHP tests PhpStorm constantly is busy with indexing this directory.

[image]

Directory `x` is part of an imported project.

Is there any reason which PhpStorm can have to exclude an excluded directory and indexes it as well? The indexing process takes forever.

[image]

Comment: Did you try Jetbrain's fix to every bug ?  File->invalidate caches and restart

Comment: Coincidentally I just tried that one, but it does not help unfortunatelly.

Comment: What is the point of adding this directory via symlink? Was it added into Settings | Languages & Frameworks | PHP > Include Path?

Comment: I am sorry Vlad, I was wrong with that. I am using a symlink for another purpose but accidentally wrote this to this issue. Thanks for noticing. And yes, it was added to that list.

Comment: Directories in Include Path will be indexed at least once to provide a completion data. For example the same happens with composer packages - they are excluded but added into include path so they won't participate in refactoring and other codebase tasks but completion for them will still work. If you do not need anything from that dir, you can remove it from Include Path.

Comment: The directory which is included in the Include Path is required. It is a child directory of that one which is being indexed but which is not required.

Comment: So directory `x` is excluded but there's `x/y` that is added into Include Path? And PhpStorm indexes whole `x` with all the subfolders? Are there any symlinks in other places that would point to `x`?

Comment: I have directory `x` which is a child of directory `y` which is added to the Include path. So excluded directory `x` is within this included directory. That's what PhpStorm does indeed. No, there are no symlinks pointing to directory `x`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Things to try (from Jetbrain team):

- Remove "Add packages as libraries" checkbox at `Preferences` |
  `Languages & Frameworks` | `PHP` | `Composer` (click Ok to save).
- Check that you don't have those excluded directories added as `include path` at `Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | PHP` afterward.

Test by rebuilding cache `File` | `Invalidate Caches / Restart...`

I encountered this problem when I had the root project path listed in the `include path` and filed it as a bug and they suggested these things.

Comment: I had this issue after updating to 2019.1; the second hint solved it for me: The project root was listed there. No idea how/why that entry was there and why it worked on previous versions though.

Comment: This worked wonders for projects I have with local composer symlinks where I was getting recursive indexing killing PHPStorm.